# Options to model JSON data in a Postgresql database?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a JSON file with data about employees and their skills. I need to model the data somehow in a PostgreSQL database (and the reason is related to the application we are developing).

The JSON file has a lot of data that I don't really need for my application (at least for now). I only need a few columns: Employee ID, Name, Qualifications. But the rest of the data should be stored in the table (only temporarily, as this is still a POC).

### Data

```
{
  "employee": {
  "ID": 654534543,,
  "Name": "Max Mustermann",
  "Email": "max.mustermann@firma.de",
  "skills": [
    {"name": python, "level": 3},
    {"name": c, "level": 2},
    {"name": openCV, "level": 3}
    ],
  },
"employee":{
  "ID": 3213213,,
  "Name": "Alex Mustermann",
  "Email": "alex.mustermann@firma.de",
  "skills":[
    {"name": Jira, "level": 3},
    {"name": Git, "level": 2},
    {"name": Tensorflow, "level": 3}
    ],
  }
};
```

I thought of creating a table with the columns: Employee ID as primary key, CHAR for the name, array for the skills and JSONB for the rest of the information about the employee.

### TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    position VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR (255),
        skills TEXT [],
        join_date DATE,      

);
```

Some factors to keep in mind: the data should be periodically updated (lets say once a month), the application should use the database to query one (or more) employee ID(s) who are covering certain required skill set(and skill levels). And so far we are not sure if we are going to query json fields (but could be possible in near future)

also, the data is complicated and dense (what I attached below is merely a simplified sample), so I guess querying directly from a JSONB column would not be convenient (as mentioned in other similar questions)

My questions now are:
1- Would the proposed data model meet the required conditions, we have a huge json data file (fast search for employee skills, scalable, easy/fast query and retrieval of employee data (for e.g employee id)?

2- What should be considered when developing a relational database schema?

3- Would there be advantages to splitting the data into multiple tables? e.g. one table for employee personal data with employee ID as primary key, one table for skills with employee ID as foreign key and a text field for skills, one JSON table for the rest of the data.

I am using PostgreSQL 15.1 on windows 10. I am also still getting familiar with PostgreSQL databases.

much thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
create table employee (
  id bigint not null primary key,
  name text not null,
  email text not null
);

create table skill (
  id bigint generated always as identity primary key,
  skill_name text not null unique
);

create table employee_skill (
  id bigint generated always as identity primary key,
  employee_id bigint not null references employee(id),
  skill_id bigint not null references skill(id),
  skill_level int not null,
  unique (employee_id, skill_id)
);
```

Then, to populate the schema (after correcting the errors with the JSON):

```
with indata as (
  select '[
  {
  "ID": 654534543,
  "Name": "Max Mustermann",
  "Email": "max.mustermann@firma.de",
  "skills": [
    {"name": "python", "level": 3},
    {"name": "c", "level": 2},
    {"name": "openCV", "level": 3}
    ]
  },
  {
  "ID": 3213213,
  "Name": "Alex Mustermann",
  "Email": "alex.mustermann@firma.de",
  "skills":[
    {"name": "Jira", "level": 3},
    {"name": "Git", "level": 2},
    {"name": "Tensorflow", "level": 3}
    ]
  }
]'::jsonb as j
), expand as (
  select emp, skill
    from indata
         cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(j) as el(emp)
         cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(emp->'skills') as sk(skill)
), insemp as (
  insert into employee (id, name, email)
  select distinct (emp->>'ID')::bigint, emp->>'Name', emp->>'Email'
    from expand
  on conflict (id) do update
    set name = excluded.name, email = excluded.email
  returning *
), insskill as (
  insert into skill (skill_name)
  select distinct skill->>'name'
    from expand
  on conflict (skill_name) do nothing
  returning *
), allemp as (
  select * from insemp union select * from employee
), allskill as (
  select * from insskill union select * from insskill
), insempskill as (
  insert into employee_skill (employee_id, skill_id, skill_level)
  select e.id as employee_id, s.id as skill_id, 
         (i.skill->>'level')::int as skill_level
    from expand i
         join allemp e on e.id = (i.emp->>'ID')::bigint
         join allskill s on s.skill_name = i.skill->>'name'
  on conflict (employee_id, skill_id) do update
    set skill_level = excluded.skill_level
  returning *
)
delete from employee_skill
 where (employee_id, skill_id) not in 
  (select employee_id, skill_id from insempskill 
    union 
   select employee_id, skill_id from employee_skill)
;
```

See [working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/39WOyBPa)

Comment: thanks, my problem now is how to select the data from the json file? I have tried a lot of ways but it seems for me difficult to integrate them using your code. do you have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: @zargawy  I'm sorry, but I missed your question in the comment.  Did you ever get past your issue?